# Javascript toArray to avoid cutting characters

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question.

This is my code, and problem with it is when i run some emojis thro this it displays them as ?, cause it cuts the emoji in half.

```
angular.module('Joe.filters').filter("initials", function() {
    return function(string) {
        if (string) {
            var words = string.split(" ");
            if (words.length) {
                string = words[0].charAt(0);
                if (words[1]) {
                    string += words[1].charAt(0);
                }
            }
        }

        return string;
    };
});
```

Now, im thinking if i can solve this with toArray, and if yes, how?
Note: if i run in console the "fix" with array.

```
j = '';
""

j.length
2

s = _.toArray(j)
[""]

s.length
1
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: those emojis in the code hurt in my eyes :D this is an encoding issue

Comment: emojis hurt everything, just thinking of it now even after i fix it with array i wont be able to apply it on colored emojis :)

Comment: I guess you need something like  `String.fromCodePoint(word.codePointAt(0))` here

Comment: or simply `[...word][0]`

Comment: [...word] doesn't fix it for me, can you elaborate a bit please !?

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, `.charAt` and `[indexing]` still work with 16-bit units, but `String.iterator` is aware of 32-bit chars. So, to extract the first char which is possibly beyond the plane 0, you have to force iteration on the string, for example:

```js
word = 'HELLO';

let b = [...word][0]
// or
let [c] = word

console.log(b, c)
```

Another option is to extract the first code point and convert it back to a character:

```
let a = String.fromCodePoint(word.codePointAt(0))
```

To answer the bonus question, I have this rather trivial function in my "standard repertoire"

```
let first = ([a]) => a
```

Using this func, your `initials` logic can be written as

```
let initials = str => str.split(' ').slice(0, 2).map(first).join('')
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand now

Comment: just curious, which approach would you use and where would you implement it exacly? if you have a minute to spare!