# counting the number of times a character is used in a string for all of a strings characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Write a function called strLetterCount which accepts a string and returns a new string with each character followed by by the number of times it appears in the string.

For example:

```
strLetterCount("taco"); // "t1a1c1o1"
```

My code is way off the mark here but this is what I got...

I was going to keep going for each letter and then from try and return the correct string. I know this is not a good way to go about it. Any help?

```js
function strLetterCount(str) {

  var countA = 0;
  var countB = 0;
  var countC = 0;
  var countD = 0;
  var countE = 0;
  var countF = 0;
  var countG = 0;
  var countH = 0;
  var countI = 0;
  var countJ = 0;
  var countK = 0;
  var countL = 0;
  var countM = 0;
  var countN = 0;
  var countO = 0;
  var countP = 0;
  var countQ = 0;
  var countR = 0;
  var countS = 0;
  var countT = 0;
  var countU = 0;
  var countV = 0;
  var countW = 0;
  var countX = 0;
  var countY = 0;
  var countZ = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++);
  if (str[i] === 'a') {
    countA++;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++);
  if (str[i] === 'b') {
    countB++;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++);
  if (str[i] === 'c') {
    countC++;
  }
  return {"a":countA,"b":countB,"c":countC}
}

console.log(
  strLetterCount("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
)
```

Comment: Check here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035837/write-a-javascript-function-to-get-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-letter-in-s]

Comment: *then from try and return the correct string* please elaborate on this

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Do you only need leters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I suggest you use an object to keep each character as a key and the appearance/frequency count as the value. Whenever you see a new character, you can add it as a new key with a value of `1`. If you see a key/character already in the object, you can add to its value/frequency count.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Your for loops are terminating at the `;` so do not count at all

Comment: I've added an answer, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through every character of the string, and count them in an object.

A simple solution would be:

```js
let str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

const count = string => {
  const characters = {};
  for (let character of string) {
    characters[character] = characters[character] + 1 || 1;
  }
  return characters;
}

console.log(count(str));
```

You can use the results as:

```
let result = count(str);
console.log(result["o"]); // 4
```

**Update**

If you need a string output, one option is to use a second loop to write out the results:

```js
let str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

const count = string => {
  const characters = {};
  let str = "";
  
  for (let character of string) {
    characters[character] = characters[character] + 1 || 1;
  }
  for (let key in characters) {
    str += `${key}${characters[key]}`
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(count(str));
```

Or, if you don't care about the format just simply:

```
return JSON.stringify(characters);
```

Comment: nice, but the output should be a string instead of an object

Comment: @NickParsons should be simple enough to construct from the object

Comment: @mplungjan it should be, but not sure whether the OP will know how...

Comment: I would [map the result against the text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60991712/295783)

Comment: Thanks all, much appreciated. Now to try and understand this code...  :/ haha

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) methods:

```js
function strLetterCount(str) {
  return Object.entries([...str].reduce(function(ac, s) {
    ac[s] = ++ac[s] || 1
    return ac;
  }, {})).flat().join('')
}

console.log(strLetterCount("taco"))
console.log(strLetterCount("chocotaco"))
```

**Explanation:**

1. Using `[...str]` we first convert the string into an array.
2. Then using `.reduce()` we are trying to get the count of each string element and the store into an object like:

   ```
   {t: 1, a: 1, c: 1, o: 1}
   ```
3. Then using `Object.entries()` we are getting data like:

   ```
   [["t", 1], ["a", 1], ["c", 1], ["o", 1]]
   ```
4. And finally using `flat()` & `join()` we get the required output format as string like `t1a1c1o1`

Comment: Would look even better with a ternary and an arrow function :)

Comment: Just wanted to keep it simple for OP (based on his/her coding style) ;-)

Comment: I think OP would have a hard time with the reduce on its own ;))) I think mine is the most readable for noobs

Comment: Agreed :)) That's why I have shared the links also, in case OP wants to learn more about it in details.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and most readable in my opinion

```js
const countChars = str => {
  const chars = {};                  // create a counter object
  const arr = str.split("");         // make an array from the characters
  arr.forEach(char => chars[char] = ++chars[char] || 1) // add counters to counter object

  return arr                         // return the array but first
    .map(char => char + chars[char]) // map to counters
    .join("");                       // and then join to string
}

console.log(countChars("Now is the time"));
```

Reduced to just char + number in the order of the first occurrence

```js
const countChars = str => {
  const chars = {};                  // create a counter object
  const arr = str.split("");         // make an array from the characters
  arr.forEach(char => chars[char] = ++chars[char] || 1) // add counters to counter object
  return Object.keys(chars)          // return the chars
    .map(char => char + chars[char]) // concatenated with counters
    .join("");                       // and then join to string
}
console.log(countChars("woof the looping loop"));
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the string without repeating numbers? For example: woof, would be w1o2f1 as opposed to w1o2o2f1?

Comment: @alexwhitmore - is the second example what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter way:

```
function strLetterCount(s) {
  return [...s].map(l=>l + s.split(l).length-1).join('')
}
```

1. You use `[...s]` to turn the string into an array of its characters.
2. Then iterate over each one.
3. Replace it with the letter, plus the number of times it occurs in the string.
4. Join the fragments together to make a string again.

Answer (score -2):

You can use an associative array instead of all those variables and write a single for to analyze the string.

```js
function strLetterCount(str) {
  var map = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (map[str[i]] === undefined)
      map[str[i]] = 0;
    map[str[i]]++;
  }
  var res = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    res += str[i] + map[str[i]];
  return res;
}
console.log(strLetterCount("taco"))
```

You can find some useful information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: How do you get rid of the repeating characters? If you had the word "woof", how do you get w1o2f1 as opposed to w1o2o2f1 ?